# VBRK & VBRP tables does not exist

Tags: abap

I am new to SAP ABAP programming, I am trying to display structure of VBRK & VBRP tables using transaction SE11, but it says table VBRK does not exist.

The book which I am using says that this table exists already. Do I need to activate something or run some code in order to use these tables?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: VBRK and VBRP are part of SAP ERP. If you have a Netweaver ABAP application server without the ERP part, you won't have those tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like SD module is not installed on your system. Now it is a part of ERP module SAP_APPL aka **Logistics and Accounting** and is usually installed by default. 
It seems that your system lacks this basic stuff. You can check its status via *System* >> *Status* >> *Component*

[image]

If you don't see it then you won't be able to use SD functionality as well.

Comment: @Alok Gupta, to ask your BASIS-Team to install it.